# Is there a way of plotting elliptic rational function offline?

Tags: special-functions

I'm studying the elliptic filter design and trying to plot the elliptic rational function, which is part of the filter equation. I have found out that there is an online way of plotting with the help of the Wolfram Function Repository.

```
Plot[ResourceFunction["EllipticRationalR"][5, 1.1, x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

I'm confused with the definition of the discrimination factor in the elliptic rational function. It depends on the elliptic rational function in some conditions and is part of the function itself. So, there seems to be no explicit form of the function. That's why I have no idea how to plot it without the ResourceFunction.

Meanwhile, the definition of the discrimination factor and the elliptic rational function from https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EllipticRationalR are different from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_rational_functions

The former gives

[image: wf1]

and the latter gives

[image: wk1]

The former says

[image: wf2]

and the latter says

[image: wk2]

I'm not sure if they are equivalent. It looks like not.

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand you question. You can use `ResourceFunction` even without the internet connection (ie. offline), if you happened to use it once before. The function is automatically downloaded and cached in your system at the first usage. If you are asking for the implementation of the function, you can click on the [Source Notebook](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EllipticRationalR) button in the top right corner, and you can see the code for yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I think the answer to my first question is clear. We need to code the function and the discrimination factor. There is no such explicit mathematical expression in MMA. But prior to that, the two sources have different definitions. Which one is correct? @Domen